# Pushing a ABUnknownPersonViewController onto a navigation controller results in having no Navigation Bar - Any ideas?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I'm working with the Address Book UI API on iPhone SDK 3.0.  I want to present to the user the ability to create a new user, or add to an existing one, so I am using the ABUnknownPersonViewController.

I have an existing navigation stack (with only 2 other views on it).  Trouble is when I push the ABUnknownPersonViewController onto it, it shows up animated, etc. But there is no navigation bar, so no way to cancel.

My code snippet is as follows

```
newPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController  alloc] init];
newPersonViewController.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
newPersonViewController.displayedPerson = person;
newPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
newPersonViewController.allowsActions = NO;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newPersonViewController animated:YES];
```

Note: the current view controller does have a title, so that's not the issue.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
[ [ self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:BOOL animated:BOOL]
```